# How to show directory structure in tree with checkboxes in java?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, tree

I want to show directory structure in a tree:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File sourceDirectory = new File("C:\\myFolder");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode sourceRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(sourceDirectory);

    DefaultTreeModel sourceModel = new DefaultTreeModel(sourceRoot);
    JTree sourceTree = new JTree();
    
    sourceTree.setModel(sourceModel);
    sourceTree.setShowsRootHandles(true);

    sourceRoot.removeAllChildren();
    sourceModel.reload();
    File rootFile = (File) sourceRoot.getUserObject();

    addFiles(rootFile, sourceModel, sourceRoot);
}

    protected void addFiles(File rootFile, DefaultTreeModel model, DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
    for (File file : rootFile.listFiles()) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());
        model.insertNodeInto((MutableTreeNode) child, root, root.getChildCount());
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            addFiles(file, model, child);
        }
    }
}
```

**thes result is these:**

[image]

but i want to add checkbox to each tree item, how can i that?

Comment: You can refer to these example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CheckBoxNodeTreeSample.htm & http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077762/core-java/swing-based-tree-layouts-with-checkboxtree.html

Comment: How can i use that sample in my code?

Comment: What do the check boxes indicate?  Selected, fluffy, drip-dry..?  See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) (just because it is vaguely related - you might pick up some tips).